# Magento Upgrade results in a blank admin page

Tags: magento-1.9

I've got a Magento web site that I've been working on after having shelved the project for a while. First thing I need to address is getting Magento up to date to resolve some insecurities.

First obvious thing I did was go the Magento downloader and just choose to bring all the modules up to date. Upon completion the front end was just fine but whenever I tried to get to the admin control panel I would just get a blank screen.

It would not get as far as asking for your credentials, it would give you the whole session key in the URL but just a blank page.

I've since tried just updating the Magento core packages alone and got the same result. I tried a giga-zillion other combinations of upgrades like just updating incrementally to the next version rather than current version.

A few of the add on packages I can upgrade and no problem but ANYTHING to try and upgrade the Mage core packages gives me a fully working front end and a blank page for the back end.

If I do the FULL upgrade I pretty much get zero errors reported to the console. That led me to try and just fix the admin panel but hours of research later, just no luck. Obviously my Magento install is useless if I can't manage it via the back end.

Any thoughts? Here's a list of the modules installed and what the downloader says is current...

```
Package Name    Installed   Available
Cm_RedisSession 1.8.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.8.0.0) 
    Redis session   
Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.0) 
    Default interface for Adminhtml 
Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.0) 
    This is a Magento themes base   
Interface_Frontend_Default  1.9.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.0) 
    Default interface for Frontend  
Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default  1.9.0.1 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.1) 
    This is a RWD themes base   
Interface_Install_Default   1.9.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.0) 
    Default interface for Install   
Lib_Cm  1.8.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.8.0.0) 
    Redis adapter for Zend_Cache    
Lib_Credis  1.8.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.8.0.0) 
    Credis Library  
Lib_Google_Checkout 1.8.1.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.8.1.0) 
    Google Checkout Library 
Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.1 (stable)   1.51.1.2 (1.51.1.1) 
    Javascript Calendar for Magento 
Lib_Js_Ext  1.7.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.7.0.0) 
    Extjs Javascript Libraries for Magento  
Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.0) 
    Javascript Libraries for Magento    
Lib_Js_Prototype    1.7.0.0.5 (stable)  1.9.2.1 (1.7.0.0.5) 
    Prototype and Scriptaculous Javascript Libraries for Magento    
Lib_Js_TinyMCE  3.4.7.1 (stable)    3.5.11.1 (3.4.7.1) 
    TinyMCE Javascript Libraries for Magento    
Lib_LinLibertineFont    2.8.14.1 (stable)   2.8.14.2 (2.8.14.1) 
    Libertine Open Fonts Project fonts for PDF print-outs   
Lib_Mage    1.8.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.8.0.0) 
    Mage Library    
Lib_Magento 1.9.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.0) 
    Magento Library 
Lib_Phpseclib   1.5.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.5.0.0) 
    Phpseclib Library   
Lib_Varien  1.9.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.0) 
    Varien Library  
Lib_ZF  1.12.3.0 (stable)   1.12.10.1 (1.12.3.0) 
    Zend Framework  
Lib_ZF_Locale   1.12.3.0 (stable)   1.12.10.1 (1.12.3.0) 
    Zend Framework Locale   
Mage_All_Latest 1.9.0.1 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.1) 
    Metapackage for latest Magento 1.9.0.0 release  
Mage_Centinel   1.9.0.1 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.1) 
    3D Secure Card Validation   
Mage_Compiler   1.9.0.1 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.1) 
    This module compiles all files of a Magento installation and creates a single include path to increase performance  
Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.0) 
    Magento Administration Panel    
Mage_Core_Modules   1.9.0.1 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.1) 
    Collection of Magento Core Modules  
Mage_Downloader 1.9.0.1 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.1) 
    Magento Downloader  
Mage_Locale_de_DE   1.9.0.0 (stable)    
    de_DE locale    
Mage_Locale_en_US   1.9.0.0 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.9.0.0) 
    en_US locale    
Mage_Locale_es_ES   1.9.0.0 (stable)    
    es_ES locale    
Mage_Locale_fr_FR   1.9.0.0 (stable)    
    fr_FR locale    
Mage_Locale_nl_NL   1.9.0.0 (stable)    
    nl_NL locale    
Mage_Locale_pt_BR   1.9.0.0 (stable)    
    pt_BR locale    
Mage_Locale_zh_CN   1.9.0.0 (stable)    
    zh_CN locale    
Magento_Mobile  1.8.0.0.23.2 (stable)   1.9.2.1 (1.8.0.0.23.2) 
    Magento Mobile Xml Interface    
Phoenix_Moneybookers    1.3.2.1 (stable)    1.9.2.1 (1.3.2.1) 
    Moneybookers payment gateway integration    
Mobile_Shoppe_Responsive_Magento_Theme  1.0.2 (stable)  
    A highly scalable and robust responsive magento theme for all business stores   
magento_absolute_theme_free 1.8.1 (stable)  2.0.0 (1.8.1) 
    Magento Absolute Theme  
news_module 0.1.2 (stable)  0.1.3 (0.1.2) 
    The News Module Extension allows you to display news on your website for viewers    
Aoe_TemplateHints   0.0.2 (stable)  
    Advanced Template Hints 
Noovias_Cron    1.0.1 (stable)  
    Magento Module Noovias_Cron 
TOPefekt_Magesms    1.1.1 (stable)  1.4.2 (1.1.1) 
    SMS notification & SMS marketing module for Magento 
Gosquared_Livestats 0.1.7 (beta)    
    GoSquared for Magento enables you to monitor your Magento site's traffic in real-time.  
Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus  0.11.5 (beta)   0.16.7 (0.11.5) 
    Additional features for the default GoogleAnalytics module. 
ET_IpSecurity   2.0.1 (stable)  2.1.1 (2.0.1) 
    Extension gives you ability to restrict access to your website by IP address or to close your shop for maintenance. 
Briel_VisitorIpSecurity 0.1.0 (stable)  0.3.1 (0.1.0) 
    Allows user to see what ip's visited the store, block, watch, whitelist those ip's  
zendesk 1.3.0 (stable)  2.0.8 (1.3.0) 
    Zendesk helps you deliver the best customer support to your customers.  
Zero1_Crondoctor    1.0.6 (stable)  
    Crondoctor  
J2T_LIGHTBOX    0.1.1 (stable)  
    J2t Lightbox using the well known Lightbox2 
File_System 1.0.0 (stable)  
    Magpleasure File System is a professional tool that is aimed at Magento files' editing straight from the administrative panel. It can be convenient to use it, when slight changes should be made to the system files. Then ftp or ssh connections are too expensive and difficult to use. Using File System you can easily do all the necessary operations 
dJ3Tr3QdSBQgWmBW    1.0.2 (stable)  
    CheetahSender Connector for Magento 
Insider 0.1.0.2 (beta)  
    Magento debug console   
IG_LightBox2    1.0.0 (stable)  
    IDEALIAGroup LightBox for Magento   
Easy_Template_Path_Hints    0.2.0 (stable)  
    Easy Template Path Hints extension is used to turn on the template path hints for frontend
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Since my the backend was broken even when trying incremental updates I opted for the full meal deal upgrade. Here's what I did...

```
cd /magento_folder
cd /magento_folder
rm -rf  var/cache/*   var/session/*
chmod -R 777 /magento_folder
chmod 550 ./mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage list-installed
./mage list-upgrades
./mage upgrade-all
```

And that did upgrade EVERY module. Then to set it back to a functional state, I did this...

```
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
chmod -R 644 ./*
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 ./mage
rm -f maintenance.flag
```

I restarted Apache and I am able to get into the front end but the back end is now the dreaded "you can't get in and here's a useless error code" screen.

I assumed you meant to edit the index.php rather than index.html file and I followed your edits AND I also added this to my .htaccess file...

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on 
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log /home/path/public_html/var/log/system.log
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true
```

And low and behold I got some useful information back! Well, if I could decode the message I think it's useful. Here's what it says (sorry, I have no clue as how to make the following text flow properly)...

```
Warning: include(TM/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/beta-deadbolt/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

#0 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(TM/Core...', '/var/www/beta-d...', 94, Array)
#1 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('TM_Core_Model_O...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('TM_Core_Model_O...')
#4 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1346): class_exists('TM_Core_Model_O...')
#5 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('tmcore/observer', Array)
#6 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::getModel('tmcore/observer', Array)
#7 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1335): Mage::getSingleton('tmcore/observer')
#8 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#9 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#10 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#11 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#12 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /var/www/beta-deadbolt/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

So if it makes any sense to you I'd appreciate any insight you may have. Thanks!

Comment: What version did you upgrade from? In Magento's `index.html`, turn on developer mode (// comment out the if/endif lines to set it without fishing around with server variables) and remove the # comment from `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, sometimes the miserable blank screen turns into a line of test that tells you pretty quickly where Magento asphyxiated on a plastic bag. Also => [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Comment: Thanks, Fiasco Labs. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you should avoid upgrading by Magento connect when it goes pear shaped it's hard to diagnose what has gone wrong. In your position I would restore to a known working version of the shop and then try then upgrade manually (no magento connect) and troubleshoot from there.